# How is the Borel-Cantelli Lemma being used in Chow and Robbins' paper on fair games?

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

In Y.S. Chow and H. Robbins' [On Sums of Independent Random Variables with Infinite Moments and “Fair” Games](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC221579/), on the second page (page 331 of the journal), the authors prove that the Petersburg random variable does not satisfy a generlization of the Strong Law of Large Numbers by the following argument (where $b_n:=n\log_2n$):

> $$P(x>a)\ge\frac{1}{a}\textrm{ for }a\ge1.$$
>   Hence, for any constant $c>1$ and $n\ge2$,
>   $$P(x>cb_n)\ge\frac{1}{cb_n}=\frac{1}{cn\log_2n}$$
>   and therefore,
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{P(x>cb_n)=\infty}$$
>   which implies by the Borel-Cantelli lemma that
>   $$P\left(\frac{x_n}{b_n}>c\textrm{ infinitely often}\right)=1.$$

But here, the events are not independent, so [the converse of the Borel-Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result) does not apply.  I assume they would then be using [the](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Counterpart) [counterpart](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3213220) in some way but I do not see how it applies here.

(The authors also use the Borel-Cantelli lemma in the same way throughout the rest of the paper)

Can someone explain how?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Oops; fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the events they are applying BC-converse to *are* independent.  Perhaps the confusion is that they did not write the subscript $n$ on $x.$

The relevant events are $\{x_n >b_nc\}$ where $x_n$ is the winnings on the $n$-th game. The outcomes of the individual games are assumed independent of one another.

They presumably omitted the subscript $n$ when expressing $P(x_n> b_n c)$ because the winnings are also identically distributed.